# Подключение сертификата из переменной домена

Tags: nginx

Интересует вопрос с подключением сертификата с помощью переменной домена. 
Судя по документации

> Начиная с версии 1.15.9 в имени файла можно использовать переменные при использовании OpenSSL 1.0.2 и выше

Требования соблюдены, но ничего не работает. Может у кого есть идеи?

Код в студию )

```
server {

    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    server_name ~^(?<sub>[\w]+\.)?(?<domain>[\w]+\.[\w]+)$;


    if ($host = $server_addr) {

        return 444;

    }

    if ($sub != "") {

        return $scheme://$domain$request_uri;

    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/privkey.pem;

}
```

Comment: «Ничего не работает» в студию. В смысле в error.log что? Какие ошибки запроса?